# Spawn objects in same place on screen on different aspect ratios, but retain distances between one another

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-screen-support

I am trying to make connect the dots game in landscape mode, and i need to spawn dots from coordinates(0-1000) in json file onto screen. It's easy to map out different viewport size to coordinates and make them spawn in same location from the edges / center of the screen, but since when you connect the dots it's suppose to be a drawing I don't want it to strech. F.e 4/3 display and 21/9 one will stretch the drawing completely differently. How can I make sure it looks the same on all devices?

I am thinking of making an invisible rectangular shape in the middle of the screen with a size 1000x1000 or max screen height) and maping coordinates to that shape, so the drawing will always be in center of the screen and will always look exactly the same, but not sure if it's possible to get a specific point in shape.

I just think there's easy solution and I overcomplicate this.

Comment: If this is using the `Canvas` you can map against a default size and then use a [`CanvasScaler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html)